# Dividing a integer equally in X parts

Tags: php, math

I'm looking for a efficient way in PHP to divide a number in equal part. Number will always be integer (no float).

Let's say that I have an array $hours with values from "1" to "24" ($hours['1'], etc) and a variable $int containing an integer. What I want to acheive is spreading the value of $int equally in 24 parts so I can assing the value to each corresponding array entries. (Should the number be odd, the remaining would be added to the last or first values in the 24).

Regards,

Comment: I don't know much PHP, but dividing a number into equal parts is usually done with `/`...

Comment: @larsmans True. But since the result can be a even number, I'm kind of stuck on possibilities (eg: 400 / 24 = 16.667, and cannot be spread equally).

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray: What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: @Truth : I guess I'd have to spread the remainer over the 24 parts, or if the remainer is only 1, add it to the first of last part. I'm actually not sure about the method for that either, but I can't really round() things up, as it might end of substracting or adding a number to the total (I think?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the algorithm you're looking for; it evenly spreads an integer `N` over `K` cells:

```
for i = 0 to K
    array[i] = N / K    # integer division

# divide up the remainder
for i = 0 to N mod K
    array[i] += 1
```

Comment: There you go! I didn't for once think that I could do a for loop with the N / K operation as the condition to stop. I just learned something here, and it works marvelously ! Thank you !

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray: please check out the correction that Zombaya just made to my algorithm; the loop should run up to `N mod K`, not `N / K`.

Comment: Could you just explain me what is the difference between N mod K and N / K at the end? I don't seem to see any difference while testing the two solutions...

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray: then your test doesn't cover all the appropriate cases. When you divide N by K, you get a remainder of N mod K and that's what you need to "smear out" over the array. In some cases, e.g. N=3 and K=2, N/K == N mod K, but not in general.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
<?php
$num = 400;
$val = floor($num/24);

for($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {
    $arr[$i] = $val;
}

$arr[0] += $num - array_sum($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function split($x, $n) 
{ 
    // If we cannot split the  
    // number into exactly 'N' parts 
    if($x < $n) 
        echo (-1); 

    // If x % n == 0 then the minimum  
    // difference is 0 and all  
    // numbers are x / n 
    else if ($x % $n == 0) 
    { 
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) 
        { 
            echo ($x / $n); 
            echo (" "); 
        } 
    } 

    else
    { 
        // upto n-(x % n) the values  
        // will be x / n  
        // after that the values  
        // will be x / n + 1 
        $zp = $n - ($x % $n); 
        $pp = $x / $n; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) 
        { 
            if($i >= $zp) 
            { 
                echo (int)$pp + 1; 
                echo (" "); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                echo (int)$pp; 
                echo (" "); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 

// Driver code      
$x = 5; 
$n = 3; 
split( $x, $n);
```