# Divide a list into fixed number of list in java

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to divide a list into a fixed number of list

Example 1

Input - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Number of lists - 4

Output- [1,2], [3,4], [5,6],[7,8]

Example 2

Input - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Number of lists - 4

Output- [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8],[9,10]

Not necessarily the order of elements should be fixed

I tried few examples but most of them were based on dividing the elements in chunks but not in a fixed number list

I do have this solution but I am interested if there is a better way especially in java 8

```
    
    
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

    int listIteration=0;
    int numberOfSublist = 4;
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> intmap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int mapIteration = 1; mapIteration < numberOfSublist +1; mapIteration++) {
        intmap.put(mapIteration, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    while(listIteration<intList.size()) {
        for (int mapIteration = 1; mapIteration < numberOfSublist +1; mapIteration++) {
            if(listIteration==intList.size()) {
                break;
            }
            intmap.get(mapIteration).add(intList.get(listIteration++));
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you decide size of each partition? is that from input?

Comment: @VeKe The partition which is 4 in this case will be an input. The size of input array can be anything

Comment: No idea why my question has downvotes. if anything is missing I can add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Please refer to this solution below for partitioning in N times,

Java 8

```
class SamplePartition
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        final int N=4;
        System.out.println(part(l,N));
    }
        
        private static <T> List<List<T>> Part(List<T> objs, final int N) {
        return new ArrayList<>(IntStream.range(0, objs.size()).boxed().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(e->e%N,Collectors.mapping(e->objs.get(e), Collectors.toList())
                        )).values());
    }
}
```

Using [Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/12.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int))

```
`List<List<Integer>> partitionedLists = Lists.partition(intList, partition`);
```

[Apache Commons Util](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

```
List<List<Integer>> partitionedLists = ListUtils.partition(largeList, partition);
```

Comment: In your solution the partition is taken as size of the list. What I want here is fixed number of list which is 4. The solution you provided creates 3 List. What I want is to distribute the elements of input array in 4 list

Comment: Hi @sujaysi have made update to divide by N time

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the list into *x* parts. You don't want to split the list into sublists where each sublist contains *x* elements. In the below code, the algorithm for determining the number of elements in each sublist comes from the [accepted] answer to [Dividing a integer equally in X parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366327/dividing-a-integer-equally-in-x-parts).

After determining the number of elements in each sublist, I simply call method `subList`, of interface `java.util.List`, with the relevant arguments.

```java
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
int n = intList.size();
int numberOfSublist = 4;
int[] arr = new int[numberOfSublist];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSublist; i++) {
    arr[i] = n / numberOfSublist;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n % numberOfSublist; i++) {
    arr[i]++;
}
int last = 0;
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSublist; i++) {
    lists.add(intList.subList(last, last + arr[i]));
    last += arr[i];
}
lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Running above code prints the following.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
```